# FromJSON instance with DataKinds

Tags: haskell, aeson, data-kinds

Trying to do the JSON de-serialisation for a data type with TypeLits, I get stuck with the following problem:

```
Couldn't match type ‘n’ with ‘2’
      ‘n’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the instance declaration at test.hs:14:10
      Expected type: aeson-0.11.2.1:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Parser
                       (X n)
        Actual type: aeson-0.11.2.1:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Parser
                       (X 2)
```

How would be the correct syntax to allow *Nat* generically in the *FromJSON* instance in the following example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Aeson
import Control.Monad (mzero)

data X (n :: Nat) where
  A :: Integer -> X 1
  B :: Integer -> X 2

instance FromJSON (X n) where
  parseJSON (Object o) = do
      v <- o .: "val"
      t <- o .: "type"
      case t of
        "a" -> return $ A v
        "b" -> return $ B v
  parseJSON _       = mzero
```

Comment: You probably need separate instances for `FromJSON (X 1)` and `FromJSON (X 2)`, or do a typecase on `n` (using a singleton). The way you have the instance written says that you can read `X n` for any `n` the *caller* chooses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you obviously cannot know the type you are going to deserialize at compile time, the exact type needs to be hidden in an existential and then restored via pattern matching. I usually use a generic `Some` type to hide phantom types.

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}

data Some (t :: k -> *) where
    Some :: t x -> Some t
```

Now you can write the instance as

```
instance FromJSON (Some X) where
    parseJSON (Object o) = do
        v <- o .: "val"
        t <- o .: "type"
        case (t :: String) of
          "a" -> return $ Some $ A v
          "b" -> return $ Some $ B v
    parseJSON _       = mzero
```

However, you also need to enable the `FlexibleInstances` extension.

Comment: You can avoid `FlexibleInstances` by using a specialized `data SomeX = forall n . SomeX (X n)`, if you like. What does the generic version win you?

Comment: Nothing in this simple example, for sure. However, I wanted to include the more generic version since you usually have several different types in an application from which you want to temporarily hide the type parameter.